# NodeJS Semaphore module: how does it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, semaphore

So here I am with my CRON call to a nodeJS application. Currently there is no guarantee that my script will not be runned several times at a given moment ; I want the script to end whenever it is already running.

[Semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) are the usual way to do it. As I'm fairly new to [NodeJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), I wanted to study and implement an existing module for that, if possible.

So I found [semaphore for node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore), seemingly the most popular pre-made solution for node. However the documentation is extremely sparse, and studying the code gives me a headache:

https://github.com/abrkn/semaphore.js/blob/master/lib/semaphore.js

I thought the module would use some kind of file to know if the process is already running, however it uses `global` to store that information. How is that? That would certainly prevent two sub-scripts to run at the same time in a single CRON call, but that wouldn't prevent two different calls to CRON to execute, would it?

Or is it possible that `global` is shared between all running NodeJS tasks?

**EDIT:**

I have to precise that this app is not an HTTP application, it is just a collection of CRONed scripts. So maybe that semaphore module isn't even the right direction to take, since it should apparently be used with `createServer()`.

Comment: I'd use plain old pid files for this.

Comment: In the example: looks like that semaphore module will block the enter of another request, while work on some expensive task, looks like it doesn't block the event loop. Maybe in your case you need another module.

Comment: Why are you using cron with node at all? You can simply use [setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/timers.html) and code your scripts to be only dependent on `node.js`, which schedules their execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `flock` command, that locks the simultaneous access to a resource, for instance:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -w 0 /path/to/cron.lock /usr/bin/node /path/to/script.js
```

The moment flock starts, it locks the lock-file you specify in the command. So flock is a pretty good way to prevent cronjobs from overlapping by using an extra Command Line tool.

There's a good explanation at: your man page or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html

Comment: It's exactly what I need! Thank you very much.

Comment: I had a subsidiary question though: when the task is over, the `*.lock` file remains in place, is this normal? Despite that, `flock` works as expected.